# gnuplot to show lables without . values

Tags: gnuplot, graph

I have a graph in `gluplot` which shows downloads per day for the month. The labels are values like

```
2500.35
1500.15
6000.45
```

How can I remove values after the `.` (dot) so that it only prints this:

```
2500
1500
6000
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove them from the input file? Why do it in gnuplot?

Answer (score 0):

The decimal format of the axis label can be set using `set format`. Example:

```
set format x "%.0f"
```

This sets the x-axis to zero decimal places.

Or you could define a `round()` function and use that while `plot`ting:

```
round(x) = x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? floor(x) : ceil(x)
```